# How can I write a query in the criteria I want with springboot in mongo, with custom query or query anatation?

Tags: java, sql, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query

How can I write a query with the following sql statement as a method in mongo with springboot?

SELECT partnerName
FROM xTable
WHERE requestId = "123"

```
@Override
public String findPartnerName(Customer customerRequest) {
    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("requestId").is(customerRequest.getId()));
    return mongoTemplate.find(query,Customer.class).toString();
}
```

The requestId value should come in a way like request.getId() that will come in the input.
How can I write this method, with a query or in this way, can you please help? I'm about to eat my head.

Comment: Have you tried something like `@Query("{'requestId': ?0}") String findPartnerNameByRequestId(Long requestId);`. Or even in your method add `findOne(query, Customer.class).getPartnerName()`

Comment: I tried to do it this way, but I couldn't, so I tried to write it in query format. How do we assign the value from the input to the requestId value?

Comment: Do you mean to call the repository like `repository.findPartnerNameByRequestId(customerRequest.getId())`? I've not tested but I think it should works.